# failedToFetch error in swift (IOS) firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am trying to fetching conversation from firebase but it's showing failedTofetch data. It is fetching from firebase but  in guard let statement it fails.

On successful i get a 2D array but on failure I get dictionary as output.

```
public func getAllMessageForConversation(with id:String,completion: @escaping (Result<[Message], Error>) -> Void){
    print("folder for conversation \(id)/message")
    database.child("\(id)/message").observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String:Any]] else{
            completion(.failure(databaseError.failedToFetch))
            print(snapshot.value!)
            return
        }
        let messages: [Message] = value.compactMap({dictionary in
            guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                  //let isread = dictionary["is_read"] as? Bool,
                  let messageId = dictionary["id"] as? String,
                  let content = dictionary["content"] as? String,
                  let senderEmail = dictionary["sender_email"] as? String,
                  let dateString = dictionary["date"] as? String,
                  //let type = dictionary["type"] as? String,
                  let date = ChatViewController.dataFormater.date(from: dateString)else{
                    return nil
                  }
            let sender = Sender(photoUrl: " ", senderId: senderEmail, displayName: name)
            
            return Message(sender: sender,
                           messageId: messageId,
                           sentDate: date,
                           kind: .text(content))
        })
        
        completion(.success(messages))
    })
    
}
```

}

[image: firebase]

[image: code]

[image: code for fetching data from firebase]

Comment: Screen snapshots are OK for things like the Firebase database, but do not use screen snapshots for the code.

Comment: Look at the snapshot value that you have printed. It is a `[String: Any]`, not an array of them, i.e., `[[String: Any]]`. So the cast will fail.

Comment: @Rob , I am trying to fetch information of all users from firebase. So it would be array of array.

Comment: First, not “array of arrays,” but rather “array of dictionaries”. Second, I understand what you wanted, but the value associated with that key simply is not an array of dictionaries, but just a plain old dictionary. If you were expecting that key to have an array of dictionaries, then your problem likely rests in your code that populated this value rather than the code retrieving the value. But just look at your firebase console (and the result of `print(snapshot.value)`) and you can see it’s not an array of values.

Comment: I am with @Rob. Doing this `[[String:Any]]` is really hard to maintain and work with. A DataSnapshot has DataSnapshot children so best bet it to leave it as that and work within the SDK. Another thing: whats `/message` in `print("folder for conversation \(id)/message")`? Lastly, something is printing 'count of conversation: 0` but there's no code in in the question that does that. Is there more code?